# MySQL - Optimise Update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

```
update CARS_LOOKUP
    INNER JOIN wheels_log ON CARS_LOOKUP.NoOfWheels= wheels_log.NoOfWheels
set CARS_LOOKUP.model= wheels_log.model
```

I am tring to update a column in a table based on a join. However mysql is going into a lock wait_timeout. cannot change my.ini OR set a global timeout. i am on 5.0.80 version, so not able to do EXPLAIN

> cars_lookup = 200K rows,
>
> wheels_log=50k rows

What would be a best way to optimise the above query in MYSQL.

Comment: `I am on 5.0.80 version, so not able to do EXPLAIN` Eh? http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html - That said, an index on noofwheels in both tables would seem useful.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
update CARS_LOOKUP c join
       wheels_log w
       on c.NoOfWheels = w.NoOfWheels
    set c.model= w.model;
```

You want an index on `wheels_log(NoOfWheels, model)`.

That said, I don't see why you would be getting a timeout on your version, unless your tables are really big.  One possibility is that `wheels_log` actually has many rows with the same `NoOfWheels`.  You can check this as:

```
select NoOfWheels, count(*)
from wheels_log
group by NoOfWheels
having count(*) > 1;
```

If there are such duplicates, they could have a big impact on performance.  You need to decide *which* of the models you want.

Comment: Yes Gordon, there are duplicates. I added a index on noofwheels on both tables....still query is going into wait_timeout....Any other way that i could write the query to achieve the same result ?

Comment: @Oggu - Not `INDEX(NoOfWheels)`, a composite `INDEX(NoOfWheels, model)`; it may make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

If this is a one-time task:

```
SET SESSION innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1200;   -- will 20 minutes suffice?
UPDATE ...;
SET SESSION innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50;  -- back to default
```

Plan B:

5.0 did not have reasonable defaults for some things.  Provide these for further analysis:

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
how much RAM?
```

Plan C:

Walk through `CARS_LOOKUP` a thousand rows at a time.  More details [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).

Plan D:

Well, you really need to be thinking about this.  It's hard to find someone to service a Model-T Ford anymore.

Upgrade 5.0 -> 5.1 -> 5.5 -> 5.6 -> 5.7 -> 8.0 -- You are a few versions out of date!  Well, actually 5.0.80 is only 9 years old.  But that may be about when EOL occurred for 5.0 (End Of Life).